# How to get image coming from curl request to my Server [PHP]

Tags: php, curl

I want to upload an image via curl request from below command.

```
curl --user name:abc --data-binary @demo.png -i localhost:80/post/index.php --output new.txt
```

Code of index.php

```
<?php
Print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I am getting output like below in txt file.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2018 08:24:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.1
Content-Length: 7075
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Array
(
    [âPNG] => ˝ŒÊêOﬂ›˙ƒ˚€√¿ú>ÿ~ﬁ€
≥W^Ç©Kf|‚`V”W8<ˆ÷ö3∞ÎòﬂœÛKõbSJOÖE•œ=Íá¯ˆ7òFÁ√ ¨Ω`3ƒ∏‘2»*®iΩ
N^J§ããÿ∆kcÙ÷ó~∞lw|uÆ˛'o|t>¯Ê|∏#bå>˙6í>á9´=`Ê
Wòıâ¿¢œúÃj¡Z'XˆÂ˘üÊï»¢uΩ∑Q”s[⁄{Ó∏xÜÔX≥Â|∂Ì¸≠#≠Ÿ|“r™ÏÜXY◊¡—pﬁ=Í’∞ÔT¨ŸÊ[z”g≠p=∂ñovÖãê[,ﬂ∞LHÕ©∂    b
[A¨ïµÄì˚uòº‰0êïô©áòÎO…`⁄2'≥ç] => 
[õï7_(eπ∂gUÌ}ÿ“—ájÌñîÀ⁄æ;}Â©√g˝¿TáŒ˙¬)ó»_¨OˇÒ!¶Á’Åõo2ƒ•ïO*Æhúúñ_˚^TbÒÊÊ∂ÓC7‚ãN^ …8ôw™Q•] => úëW≥=1£‚£jYÎõ)YUøÛ$KL ¨¥b
AttèÄÁßoÄŸÀN¡íÕ°!~q⁄<ƒaÄüí.ø8P@§ì≥(Ç∞U≠ªâ™=ƒÕ VV7ˆ∏_ç˛ãß_,ÂÂÆ^·dïPRŸ~I!Ú†]º„û%7›X\—®Pjäï-:MG◊{y{Û‚Ì;à∑n#ÚE4JŸ⁄›CP%eU pIMÛŒ´°/<}
BlÑ¯¬¨M0e¡fòµÙ$Å±¢©ŒP@tÛM¥®K~âœíe®5›C±5∫!åK.∏Ò—∫„èº·$Ëu
ﬁ_{üÆVX.ÒZD.l;Ë≈DÂó C[;zZ4´ªÔ6r®–vﬂB˛[≠Ωâù]É‚buhÑ¯o~_CÍ¢ÔÒ˜˘w]›7±≠≥Ø£ºJôôXº\™Ë¸ŸQ:Êi∑´_ˇ€70ô@Œ\zbÑk[Çx?∫è±¿aàé1≈1 ÔzÊ|IçJB'| ª†“óí«§≈ ¡;´Ω∑ÊL]≤ˆûÄI#ñçÜòÛ¯  ÁÎÛ’⁄ÅD≤¥ª=}w4#∞ïZ;H á–ûæ€˜t=C≈ó}ó“y?A *D=»-dëÚÎP“D=¿0w«@ÛƒÄã∫FÆËòØ$º›Ÿ’__R!ü¥r„iò˝¡nò˚—°ÖÀ¬KÛ∂¡æì@Ó) rL¸˛Ã5àL*~ÆVﬁzEXYÒ√@≥¶[j_ˇ¨©oãŒ*®õ|∆5‚” -Bºí\˚Îê1?‹N•åuÜòC5†5e◊sÜ\‹⁄Ÿ Ì‘>óZJÅ<O(
[π,˚û_n—≈3B"s◊»ïj«7∂:v—âÇhº∏yèaèÜBÀæ¯¬_ÉhjëoSù8Òcg†:—b
```

I want to save demo.png from any computer to my PHP server.Please some one help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload image, you should pay attention on 'Content-Type' header.
Try to add following argument into your 'curl' command:

> -H "Content-Type: image/png"

Comment: I am referring to https://tinypng.com/developers curl structure they don't have any header in it.